# A more elegant docker run command

Tags: python, linux, docker, dockerfile

I have built a docker image using a Dockerfile that does the following:

```
FROM my-base-python-image
WORKDIR /opt/data/projects/project/
RUN mkdir files
RUN rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
COPY rss-centos-7-config.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
COPY files/ files/
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv && . /opt/venv/activate
RUN yum install -y unzip
WORKDIR files/
RUN unzip file.zip && rm -rf file.zip && . /opt/venv/bin/activate && python -m pip install *
WORKDIR /opt/data/projects/project/
```

That builds an image that allows me to run a custom command. In a terminal, for instance, here is the commmand I run after activating my project venv:

```
python -m pathA.ModuleB -a inputfile_a.json -b inputfile_b.json -c
```

Arguments a & b are custom tags to identify input files. -c calls a block of code.

So to run the built image successfully, I run the container and map local files to input files:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /local/inputfile_a.json:/opt/data/projects/project/inputfile_a.json -v /local/inputfile_b.json:/opt/data/projects/project/inputfile_b.json image-name:latest bash -c 'source /opt/venv/bin/activate  && python -m pathA.ModuleB -a inputfile_a.json -b inputfile_b.json -c'
```

Besides shortening file paths, is there anythin I can do to shorten the `docker run` command? I'm thinking that adding a CMD and/or ENTRYPOINT to the Dockerfile would help, but I cannot figure out how to do it as I get errors.

Comment: What about using environment variables? Or giving script setting via stdin?

Comment: what about using `docker-compose`? is that an option?

Comment: Map `/opt/data/projects/project/` to `/local` instead to get all the files in one go (and maybe use `$PWD` if it's in the current dir). Then set an entry point so you don't need the `bash` and `source` parts.

Comment: Creating a virtual environment inside a container is a belt-and-suspenders approach. You can simplify the container significantly by installing everything system-wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to improve this.

The simplest is to run the application outside of Docker.  You mention that you have a working Python virtual environment.  A design goal of Docker is that programs in containers can't generally access files on the host, so if your application is all about reading and writing host files, Docker may not be a good fit.

Your file paths inside the container are fairly long, and this is bloating your `-v` mount options.  You don't need an `/opt/data/projects/project` prefix; it's very typical just to use short paths like `/app` or `/data`.

You're also installing your application into a Python virtual environment, but inside a Docker image, which provides its own isolation.  As you're seeing in your `docker run` command and elsewhere, the mechanics of activating a virtual environment in Docker are a little hairy.  It's also not necessary; just skip the virtual environment setup altogether.  (You can also directly run `/opt/venv/bin/python` and it knows it "belongs to" a virtual environment, without explicitly activating it.)

Finally, in your `setup.py` file, you can use a `setuptools` [`entry_points`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html) declaration to provide a script that runs your named module.

That can reduce your Dockerfile to more or less

```
FROM my-base-python-image
# OS-level setup
RUN rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
COPY rss-centos-7-config.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN yum install -y unzip
# Copy the application in
WORKDIR /app/files
COPY files/ ./
RUN unzip file.zip \
 && rm file.zip \
 && pip install *
# Typical runtime metadata
WORKDIR /app
CMD main-script --help
```

And then when you run it, you can:

```sh
docker run --rm -it \
  -v /local:/data   \  # just map the entire directory
  image-name:latest \
  main-script -a /data/inputfile_a.json -b /data/inputfile_b.json -c
```

You can also consider the `docker run -w /data` option to change the current directory, which would add a Docker-level argument but slightly shorten the script command line.